# How to create sets for a column, separated by data types?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set, unique

I want to create a set in which only the string values of a column appear. The numerical values of the column are to be stored in another set.

Comment: It would be better to provide a clear reproducible example with the matching expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['numeric'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce')
df['non-numeric'] = df['col'].mask(df['numeric'].notna())
```

Example:

```
   col  numeric non-numeric
0  abc      NaN         abc
1  123    123.0         NaN
2  123    123.0         NaN
3  NaN      NaN         NaN
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['abc', 123, '123', float('nan')]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
my_dataset = [
    {'id': 1, 'my_column': 'apple', 'value': 10},
    {'id': 2, 'my_column': 'banana', 'value': 20},
    {'id': 3, 'my_column': 30, 'value': 30},
    {'id': 4, 'my_column': 'orange', 'value': 40},
    {'id': 5, 'my_column': 50, 'value': 50}
]

string_set = {row['my_column'] for row in my_dataset if isinstance(row['my_column'], str)}
numerical_set = {row['my_column'] for row in my_dataset if isinstance(row['my_column'], (int, float))}

print(string_set)

print(numerical_set)
```